# How to read and replace a word in C++ at any location?

Tags: c++, file-handling

I modify files, by saving file content on variables/objects and then i overwrite the selected variable/object. And then i truncate file and rewrite the file with variables/objects. Is there anyway that i can replace a word in file just by using simple function?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <conio.h>
#include <fstream>
#include <sstream>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include<cstdlib>
using namespace std;


class record{
private:
date idate;
int id;
string description;
double quantity;
double wholesalecost;
double retailcost;
public:
void createfile(){
ofstream out("abc.txt");
      }

void savedata(){
ofstream write;
write.open("abc.txt",ios::app);
write<< id<<endl;
write<< description<<endl;
write<< quantity<<endl;
write<< wholesalecost<<endl;
write<< retailcost<<endl;
write.close();
}
void readdata(int i){

    ifstream in("abc.txt");
    if(!in){
        cout<<"File opening error";
        exit(1);
    }
for(int j=0;j<i;j++){
    in>>id;
    in>>description;
    in>>quantity;
    in>>wholesalecost;
    in>>retailcost;

}

in.close();


    }
void getrecord(int recordeditems){


    id=recordeditems;
    cout<<"Enter Description of Item :";
    cin>>description;
    cout<<"Enter quantity :";
    cin>>quantity;
    cout<<"Enter Wholesale cost :";
    cin>>wholesalecost;
    cout<<"Enter Retail Cost :";
    cin>>retailcost;
}
void showrecord(){

 cout<<"* Item ID Number :"<<id<<endl;
 cout<<"* Description of Item :"<<description<<endl;
 cout<<"* Quantity of Item :"<<quantity<<endl;
 cout<<"* Wholesale cost of Item :"<<wholesalecost<<endl;
 cout<<"* Retail Cost of Item :"<<retailcost<<endl;
   }
void cleardata(){
ofstream ofs;
ofs.open("abc.txt", std::ofstream::out | std::ofstream::trunc);
ofs.close();
}
};
int main()
{
record records[50];
int recordeditems; 
ifstream in("index.txt");
in>> recordeditems;    
if(!in){               
    ofstream out("index.txt");  //create output file object
    recordeditems=0;    //set default index number =zero
    out<<recordeditems;  //write index number into the file
    }
char ch;
do{
    system("cls");
    char choice;  //character which use user choice
    cout<<"Press 'A' to Add  New Records to File"<<endl;;
    cout<<"Press 'D' to Display Any Record to File"<<endl;
    cout<<"Press 'M' to Modify any existed Record to File"<<endl;
    cout<<"Enter Choice :";
    cin>>choice;
    cin.ignore(); //"ignores next line in input"
if(choice=='A'||choice=='a'){ //if choice =A or a
         recordeditems++;  //when new record comes it increment it self
        ofstream out("index.txt"); //it recreate its file with same name
        out<< recordeditems; //it then save its value in the file
    if(recordeditems==1){ //condition when no records are saved
            records[recordeditems-1].getrecord(recordeditems);                        
            records[recordeditems-1].createfile(); 
            records[recordeditems-1].savedata();   
        }
    else{
         records[recordeditems-1].getrecord(recordeditems); 
         records[recordeditems-1].savedata();   

        }
}

else if(choice=='D'||choice=='d'){
         record call; // a temporary object to read data from file
         a: //label
         system("cls"); //clear screen command use <cstdlib> library
         int i;
         cout<<"Which Recorded Item, Would you like to display :";
         cin>>i;
         if(i>recordeditems){
            cout<<"Record item is not stored yet"<<endl;
            system("pause");
            goto a;
         }
         call.readdata(i); //that temporary object reads data from file
         call.showrecord();// then display it

}
else if(choice=='M'||choice=='m'){
         int mod;
        for(int i=0;i<recordeditems;i++){
            records[i].readdata(i+1);    
        }
         cout<<"Enter which record number you want to modify :";
          cin>>mod; //which object number you want to modify ?
          cin.ignore(); //ignores the next line
          records[mod-1].getrecord(mod); 
          records[mod-1].cleardata(); 


        for(int j=0;j<recordeditems;j++){

                records[j].savedata();  

             }
 }

else{
    cout<<"Invalid Choice ";
    }
cout<<endl<<"Enter 'y' to go back to menu or press any other key to quit";
ch=_getch(); //input character with out press enter on it
}while(ch=='y'||ch=='Y');

return 0;
}
```

Comment: No. What have you tried so far?

Comment: Please show us a minimalistic example, that demonstrates what you have tried so far.

Answer (score 1):

In case you want to search through your file and replace a specific word the whole thing is easy... All you have to do is write a small search engine which will go through the whole file and then return the location of your word. then all you need to do is jump to the location erase the word and add whatever you need.

Here is a small example of a function which searches wether the searched word is present in the string array `data`. `Lines` stands for the lines of your file

```
bool inIt(std::string Input, std::string find){
    int total = Input.length();
    int findl = find.length();
    if (total < findl){ return false; }//if our base string is shorter, they can't be equal
    for (int offset = 0; offset <= total - findl; offset++){//the string with an offset mustn't be longer than the base
        std::stringstream addchar;
        for (int read = offset; read < findl + offset; read++){//read the length of the compare string
            addchar << Input[read];//read the string with an offset
        }

        //compare
        if (addchar.str() == find){
            return true;//if our new string is the same as our compare string we end searching
        }
    }
    return false;//nothing found
}
```

In order to find the Line where your string is located use this:

```
int findAt(std::string what, int fromLine=1){
    if (fromLine >= Lines){ return -1; }
    //std::cout << "searching... ";
    for (int n = fromLine; n < Lines+1; n++){
        //std::cout << std::endl << data[n] << " = ";
        bool ret = inIt(data[n], what);
        if (ret){ 
            //std::cout << "FOUND at " << n << std::endl;
            return n;
        }
    }
    //std::cout << "not found!" << std::endl;;
    return -1;
}
```

I think that you can write the last function, which will find and replace the word in the line on your own.
BTW this were snippets of one of my projects, so if I left stuff unclear, ask me.

There may be a few spelling mistakes, so sorry but I am not native

Comment: then you may want to accept that answer and or upvote :)